# Numpy array not transposing correctly

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a Python class `Fixed_Synthetic_Dataset`, and one of the parameters that it takes in is an array `controls`.

```py
class Fixed_Synthetic_Dataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, controls, responses, time_step, interpol):
        print(f'Controls shape: {controls.shape}')
        print(f'Controls type: {type(controls)}')
        if controls.ndim > 1:
            self.all_values = controls.transpose(1,2)
        else:
            self.all_values = controls
        self.responses = responses
        self.time_step = time_step
```

The issue occurs in the line `self.all_values = controls.transpose(1,2)`. I get an 'axes don't match the array' error, which I'm told occurs because the array 'controls' does not have a second or third dimension. However, as the print statements can attest, controls when I pass it in is a 3D numpy array of shape (600, 20000, 2).

For reference, here are some code snippets I used when passing it in:

```
train_x, train_y, valid_x, valid_y, test_x, test_y = get_JR_data(2000, t, noise=False)

train_set = Fixed_Synthetic_Dataset(train_x, train_y, time_step, args.interpol)
```

The array `train_x` is also (600, 20000, 2).

Here is a minimal, reproducible example:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.zeros((600, 20000, 2))
new_data = data.transpose(1,2)
```

and the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\gavin\Documents\Data Generation\transpose test.py", line 5, in <module>
    new_data = data.transpose(1,2)
ValueError: axes don't match array
```

Comment: Show us a [mcve] and the output it produces, including all `print` output and the full, exact error message, with stack trace.

Comment: Does my edit do that? Let me know if there's anything else I should put in there.

Comment: @GavinAn Please include example data in the question itself. You could maybe just do `zeros` of the same size; I'm not a NumPy expert.

Comment: Where's the `0` axis supposed to go? (The size 600 one).  With transpose you have to specify all axes.  With `swap` you just  specify 2.  Read and reread the docs.  https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html#numpy.transpose

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have a 3 dimensional array, but only specify 2 axis.
What you want to do, for example, is:

```
self.all_values = controls.transpose(1,0,2)
```

The actual order of the items given to transpose depends on the purpose of your code.
For more information on ndarray.transpose, see: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.transpose.html